# Why task cancellation takes so long in Flurl.Http DownloadFileAsync / HttpClient GetAsync

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient, cancellationtokensource, flurl

While writing a class to download images from a server in parallel (employing a consumer/producer pattern backed by the [DataFlow TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library), using an `ActionBlock` and [`Flurl.Http`](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/) facility method `DownloadFileAsync`, I've realized that cancellation was taking a lot of time. Since all download operations share a `CancellationToken` I was expecting that all tasks would cancel instantly (or almost).  In reality, if I spawn lots of parallel downloads, cancellation of all tasks/threads can take minutes. I've worked around that by setting the `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property to 10. In this way there'll be at most 10 concurrent downloads to cancel at any given time (which, still, is not an immediate action as I was expecting).

I've created a console .NET 5 program that reproduces the issue in isolation (without the DataFlow TPL, `ActionBlock`, etc.). It starts by asking the number of concurrent downloads (press enter for the default: which is 100 downloads). Then it spawn all these downloads in parallel using `Flurl.Http` (which uses `HttpClient`), passing a `CancellationToken` to each operation. Then it waits for a key to be pressed and then it cancels the pending downloads by calling the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` method. At the end, it prints some statistics including the number of successful and failed/cancelled downloads, plus the time it took for the cancellation to complete. Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl.Http;

const string imageSource = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
const int defaultCount = 100;
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int completed = 0;
int failed = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Flurl.DownloadFileAsync Cancellation test!");
Console.Write($"Number of downloads ({defaultCount}): ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
if (!int.TryParse(input, out var count)) 
    count = defaultCount;
Console.WriteLine($"Will spawn {count} parallel downloads of '{imageSource}'");

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
List<Task> tasks = new();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    tasks.Add(Download(i));

Console.WriteLine("Hit anything to cancel...");
Console.ReadKey(true);

log("Cancelling pending downloads");
var cancelMoment = watch.Elapsed;
cts.Cancel();
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
log("Downloads cancelled. Program ended!");

Console.WriteLine($"### Total cancellation time: {watch.Elapsed - cancelMoment} -> Completed: {completed}, Failed/Cancelled: {failed}");

async Task Download(int i) {
    var fn = $"test_{i}.png";
    try {
        await imageSource.DownloadFileAsync(fn, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref completed);
        log($"DONE: {fn}");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref failed);
        log($"# ERROR: {fn}/r/n >> {e.Message}");
    }
}

void log(string s) => Console.WriteLine($"{watch.Elapsed}- {s}");
```

What strikes me the most is that allowing all downloads to complete (even if I input 1000 downloads) is faster than cancelling the operation. I don't know if there is any kind of deadlock going on (which causes the operations to end after a lock timeout), or if the cancellation of these downloads are simply broken. I couldn't find a good explanation or solution for this issue.

To reproduce the issue you must hit a key to cancel the pending downloads before all downloads complete. If you time it right you can allow a few downloads to succeed. If you hit it too fast, you'll cancel all downloads. If you wait too long all downloads will have completed already.

[image: Cancelled after 1 download completed]

This run resulted in the following results:

[image: cancellation results]

It took whooping 55+ seconds to cancel the 99 pending operations. If I simply allow all downloads to complete, it takes a LOT less than the time it takes to cancel the same operations.

UPDATE

---

I've removed Flurl altogether and used HttpClient directly to download the file and the problem persists. I've changed the Downlod method to the following:

```
async Task Download(int i) {
    var fn = $"test_{i}.png";
    try {
        var r = await client.GetAsync(imageSource, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
        using var httpStm = await r.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cts.Token);
        var file = new FileInfo(fn);
        using var f = file.OpenWrite();
        await httpStm.CopyToAsync(f, cts.Token);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref completed);
        log($"DONE: {fn}");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref failed);
        log($"# ERROR: {fn}/r/n >> {e.Message}");
    }
}
```

Results are the same as with the FLURL based implementation (after all, Flurl.Http is just a wrapper around HttpClient).

UPDATE 2

---

I've changed the Download method to simply wait on a cancellable `Task.Delay` and the cancellation time of 100 operations is now around 2 seconds. While it's faster, it's not instantaneous, and by the timing of the logs on the screen it seems to me that the cancellations are being triggered sequentially and not in parallel/at once. The code for this download is:

```
async Task Download(int i) {
    var fn = $"test_{i}.png";
    try {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), cts.Token);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref completed);
        log($"DONE: {fn}");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref failed);
        log($"# ERROR: {fn}/r/n >> {e.Message}");
    }
}
```

The following screenshot shows the result with the above code:

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone have a good explanation or solution for that?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not actually checking the token until the download returns. Perhaps you should check the token before calling `DownloadAsync`

Comment: Can you please check if adding the cancellation token to the execution like: `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), cts.Token);` is your desired result?

Comment: Try it without logging to console and do not use interlocked increment. Try to print out into console only when task is started and then when all were stopped. See if minimized output will make a difference.

Comment: @quain Already did that! :-) It seems HttpClient is the culprit... It just doesn't "cancel" very well... Still researching though.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked into Flurl.Http but I assume cancellation is not sufficiently supported. If you are using .Net6 you could use [WaitAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-waitasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken)). If not you might create a Task that you can cancel and await this task with the download task within Task.WhenAny like so:

```
await Task.WhenAny(new[] { cancellableTask, downloadTask })
```

The downside is that I have no idea how to really cancel the work associated with the downloads.

Comment: The issue is exactly the cancellation of the downloads. I could just cancel the token and forget, but since I must stop the downloads gracefully and fast, a async wait is of no use for me sadly (didn't know about WaitAsync though, thank you for that :-) )

Comment: I'm updating the question because the problem also occurs with vanilla HttpClient and stream copyto operations.

Comment: I wonder if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195694/how-cancel-downloading-async might be an answer for you?

Comment: That answer uses the outdated `WebClient`. It also does not wait for the cancellation to complete.  It is equivalent of just calling `Cancel()` on the `CancellationToken` and not really wait for the downloads to be cancelled.  I also realized it happens with other cancellable tasks not tied to Flurl or HttpClient, so I'll have to dig deeper on this one, but thanks  for all the trouble.

Comment: That is strange. The only thing I would change is that I would pass the cancellation token in Download and not put the cts in the closure. Neverteless I do not think this could explain the behavour you experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the cancellation token individually to the tasks but not to the parent `Task.WaitAll()`, after you invoke `cts.Cancel()`, other tasks will have no knowledge of the cancellation request until `Download()` is invoked for each of them.

Pass the token to the parent, so it acts like an orchestrator for all tasks:

```cs
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), cts.Token);
```

Then, once the cancellation fires, remaining tasks will not be required to executed, saving you cancellation time.

```
Flurl.DownloadFileAsync Cancellation test!
Number of downloads (100):
Will spawn 100 parallel downloads of 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'
Hit anything to cancel...
00:00:03.8603945- DONE: test_3.png
00:00:03.8603937- DONE: test_41.png
00:00:03.8603967- DONE: test_12.png
00:00:03.8603920- DONE: test_22.png
00:00:03.8640374- DONE: test_27.png
00:00:03.8651895- DONE: test_57.png
00:00:03.8652114- DONE: test_64.png
00:00:03.8652039- DONE: test_1.png
00:00:03.8652149- DONE: test_10.png
00:00:03.8652222- DONE: test_0.png
00:00:03.8653910- DONE: test_2.png
00:00:03.8865928- DONE: test_28.png
00:00:03.8990767- DONE: test_11.png
00:00:03.8993285- DONE: test_20.png
00:00:03.9048105- DONE: test_6.png
00:00:03.9056048- DONE: test_68.png
00:00:03.9067027- DONE: test_69.png
00:00:03.9075434- DONE: test_54.png
00:00:03.9094678- DONE: test_5.png
00:00:03.9166961- DONE: test_50.png
00:00:03.9169709- DONE: test_13.png
00:00:03.9185492- DONE: test_87.png
00:00:03.9298495- DONE: test_7.png
00:00:03.9326280- DONE: test_43.png
00:00:03.9327424- DONE: test_33.png
00:00:03.9357554- DONE: test_45.png
00:00:03.9363720- DONE: test_37.png
00:00:03.9386855- DONE: test_30.png
00:00:03.9393222- DONE: test_95.png
00:00:03.9427672- DONE: test_14.png
00:00:03.9463875- DONE: test_84.png
00:00:03.9487063- DONE: test_34.png
00:00:03.9488809- DONE: test_80.png
00:00:03.9493661- DONE: test_90.png
00:00:03.9533510- DONE: test_17.png
00:00:03.9550988- DONE: test_85.png
00:00:03.9559576- DONE: test_71.png
00:00:03.9559739- DONE: test_31.png
00:00:03.9581015- DONE: test_52.png
00:00:03.9595559- DONE: test_89.png
00:00:03.9596396- DONE: test_61.png
00:00:03.9604608- DONE: test_36.png
00:00:03.9605789- DONE: test_26.png
00:00:03.9643205- DONE: test_25.png
00:00:03.9708155- DONE: test_18.png
00:00:03.9712862- DONE: test_39.png
00:00:03.9780414- DONE: test_98.png
00:00:03.9782002- DONE: test_42.png
00:00:03.9788898- DONE: test_48.png
00:00:03.9844171- DONE: test_15.png
00:00:03.9856963- DONE: test_16.png
00:00:03.9862520- DONE: test_96.png
00:00:03.9923971- DONE: test_58.png
00:00:03.9944836- DONE: test_59.png
00:00:04.0070565- DONE: test_40.png
00:00:04.0093207- DONE: test_29.png
00:00:04.0119729- DONE: test_55.png
00:00:04.0148981- DONE: test_24.png
00:00:04.0163724- DONE: test_32.png
00:00:04.0173879- DONE: test_9.png
00:00:04.0191403- DONE: test_46.png
00:00:04.0426426- DONE: test_23.png
00:00:04.0549689- DONE: test_81.png
00:00:04.0550977- DONE: test_4.png
00:00:04.0554659- DONE: test_63.png
00:00:04.1206750- DONE: test_21.png
00:00:04.1207557- DONE: test_44.png
00:00:04.1773007- DONE: test_65.png
00:00:04.1854760- DONE: test_62.png
00:00:04.1854846- DONE: test_38.png
00:00:04.1883149- Cancelling pending downloads
00:00:04.2348932- # ERROR: test_19.png/r/n >> A task was canceled.
00:00:04.2757044- # ERROR: test_35.png/r/n >> A task was canceled.
00:00:04.2757328- # ERROR: test_8.png/r/n >> A task was canceled.
00:00:04.2759605- # ERROR: test_56.png/r/n >> A task was canceled.
00:00:04.2763499- Downloads cancelled. Program ended!
### Total cancellation time: 00:00:00.0954826 -> Completed: 70, Failed/Cancelled: 4
00:00:04.2845926- # ERROR: test_70.png/r/n >> A task was canceled.
```

Mind you cancellation time is much smaller since we only need to cancel the tasks being executed at that moment, instead of all tasks getting notified of the cancellation by themselves. We completed 70 tasks, 4 of them are cancelled, and the remaining was just dropped, resulting much faster cancellation time.

Comment: If I do this I'll cancel the WaitAll, each task will still be run, the WaitAll itself will be cancelled and that's not what I need. It's the same as calling Cancel() on the CancellatioToken and not wait for completion. The original scenario where this was happening was inside an ActionBlock of a DataFlow pipeline with unbounded parallelism.

Comment: I'm awarding you answer with 50 points from the bounty even though it didn't exactly answer the problem. I think that there's a problem with Task cancellation in HttpClient: it doesn't play well with cancellation. That said I've wrapped the calls in a ``Task.Run`` which itself receives the cancellation token, this way the process does not even begin if I cancel it early. I've also limited the parallelism to 5 to preventing starving of the thread pool. Thanks for you effort anyway!